# Snake game - only draws a max length of 2 for the snake

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make the snake game in processing, and I've encountered a problem where after eating a first apple, the snake's length increases to 2, but after eating more, the snake's length remains the same. Not sure what the problem is with how I am trying to accomplish th

Comment: Just think how the for-loop in `movePlayer` works. First, it runs with `i=0`, then `i=1`, ..... Replace the `i` in the loop body by the value and look what it does.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please elaborate? With this, I'm trying to move the current location, which is at index 0, to index 1, and then whatever was in index 1 to index 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a simplified version of your for-loop in `movePlayer`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
    snakeLocationX[i + 1] = snakeLocationX[i];
```

Writing this code without a loop gives:

```
snakeLocationX[1] = snakeLocationX[0];
snakeLocationX[2] = snakeLocationX[1];
snakeLocationX[3] = snakeLocationX[2];
```

This means the value of `snakeLocationX[0]` is copied step by step to all other array items.

Solution: Start the for-loop with the highest `i` value and decrement.